# Let $G=\left\langle a \right\rangle$ Show that any subgroup of G is also cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

Suppose H is an arbitrary subgroup of G and $H\neq \{e\}$. Let $a^{k_{0}}\in H$. Let $b=a^{t}$ be an arbitrary member of H such that $k_{0}\le t$. For some $q,r$ s.t. $t=k_{0}q+r$, then $a^{t}=a^{k_{0}q+r}=a^{k_{0}q}a^{r}$ for $0\le r\lt k_{0}$. Since $k_{0}\le t$, $r=0$. Thus, $a^{t}=a^{k_{0}q}$ and therefore H is cyclic. Since H was arbitrary, any subgroup of a cyclic group is also cyclic.

Is this proof correct? Any possible improvements welcome

Comment: If $a^{k_0}=e$ so $a^{k_0 q}=e^q=e$, so unless your subgroup is the trivial one there is a mistake

Comment: @That was a mistake. Instead, i just stated that $a^{k_{o}}\in H$ without the condition. That should fix it. Thanks

Comment: Alternative: wlog, $~H \neq \{e\}.~$ Let $~n~$ denote the smallest positive integer such that $~b = a^n \in H.~$  Then, prove that $~H = \langle b\rangle.$

Comment: "Since $k_0<t$, $r=0$." Why should this be true?

Comment: 1. Posts don't start on the title (just like letters don't start on the envelope). Make sure the question you are trying to ask is included in the post itself and not just in the title line. 2. The `solution-verification` tag description says:  ""Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so.". Your post, right now, is just "Is my proof correct?" and as such is off topic.

Comment: @GregMartin Suppose $k_{0}\ge t$ If $k_{0}>t$ then $r>1$. However, $k_{0}=t$ then $r>1$ So in fact i should have denoted $k_{0}\le t$. Thanks

Comment: @ArturoMagidin understood

Comment: The step I identified in my earlier comment is (still) unjustified.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.  Compare your proof to the linked common  proofs. If any questions remain then ask questions in comments on these proofs. If that fails, then edit your question to identify *precisely* which step you question, and why so.

Comment: @GregMartin Well $k_{0}\le t$ implies that its the smallest element in the set

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It would be helpful if you start with the integer $k_0$, which is the least one such that $a^{k_0}\in H$. This would a generator of $H$.